# Why does my Evo 850 perform way below spec?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, performance

My Samsung 850 Evo is the only SSD in my setup (+ 1X Intenso 240 M.2 SATA and 1x Intenso 120GB SATA, besides it) that performs way under the public benchmark tests, particularly when writing.

[image: My current benchmark]

Its already a couple of years old, formatted in Ext4 currently and tested of Windows 10.

Comment: It would help if you'd link the benchmark tests. Also keep in mind that many modern SSDs are "optimized" for benchmark tests by using some high-speed intermediate buffers. In real life, once they get filled while writing, you are back to the "real" speed of the SSD.

Comment: Is the disk full? If it is formatted as ext4 then what did you do to test it in Windows? Have you cleared and TRIM'ed or optimised the disk in Windows? If you have then did you leave it a while for the controller to do it's job freeing up blocks?

Comment: As far as I know, TRIMing and stuff goes automatically in all modern OS. Am I wrong? I did nothing of that sorts, will look into it. I used the SSD before as root and home of a Linux based OS, so it should have TRIM for sure. Check this with my distribution

Comment: TRIM might be "automatic" but it only happens periodically and is not necessarily enabled by default. Windows enables the use of TRIM after checking the disk type which can happen on installation. Windows will not TRIM ext4 partitions nor will Linux TRIM Windows partitions. Even in Linux you need to see `discard` in your [fstab](https://www.everything-linux-101.com/how-to/enable-trim-ssd-solid-state-drives/) to be sure it is TRIM'ing as it goes or have a `crontab` running daily. Check in Windows: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-ensure-trim-enabled-windows-10-speed-ssd-performance

Answer (score 0):

The performance of your disk is within the parameters measured by other
858,824 users, albeit yours are on the low spectrum.

From
[UserBenchmark : Samsung MZ-75E250B 850 Evo 250GB](https://ssd.userbenchmark.com/Samsung-850-Evo-250GB/Rating/2977):

[image]

As performance depends on more parameters than just the disk,
such as the CPU, bus and RAM, I wouldn't consider from your results
that the disk is malfunctioning or performing below its specs.

Comment: It is, since the others are performing fine.
3500X, ASUS B550 and the same SATA bus on which as an example, the Intenso 2.5 hangs.